# RegEx for matching/replacing big ( { and } ) brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I need to match / replace these brackets in JavaScript:

I need like:

```
element { property: value }
```

to be:

```
element   property: value
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can strip those bracket with the replace method using a global regular expression:

```
var str="element { property: value }";
str=str.replace(/[\{\}]/g, "");
```